# Firefox 4b11 version mywebsite image,css,js not loading

Tags: javascript, css, image

One of the my website working all other browser except Firefox 4 beta version.. Firefox 4 having problem for loging css, image, js file. I checked in HTTPwatcher the request was  not sending to server.

SITE: https://www.logaway.com/

Same server sub domains are working fine..

URL: http://articles.logaway.com/

Please help me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a security issue. Firefox is showing a lot of [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives) errors if you check the Error Console. Select `Tools -> Error Console` from the menu or press Ctrl+Shift+J if you are using Windows.

The main error seems to be because you are using `https` and your server does not support [RFC-5746](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746) (see [CVE-2009-3555](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2009-3555))